Nuxt Image - External images are not processed
I'm working on a Nuxt 3 project. The app is rendered statically.
I use the Nuxt-Image plugin to optimize images.
The images are loaded from an external source called freeda.
Stack:
"nuxt": "^3.9.1",
"@nuxt/image": "^1.6.0",

According to the documentation, the images used should be downloaded during the build process (nuxt generate) - and generated in the build folder in the /_ipx folder. However, that doesn't happen.
The original paths to the provider are still stored in the compiled HTML files.
<!-- generated .html file in /.output/public-->
<img src="https://api.test.freeda.cloud/public/uploads/543ec95c-db2d-11eb-8d19-0242ac130004/4d80dd04-237f-487d-aacd-61ab4625875a-600.png?format=webp" onerror="this.setAttribute('data-error', 1)" loading="lazy" data-nuxt-img="" style="width:100%;" srcset="https://api.test.freeda.cloud/public/uploads/543ec95c-db2d-11eb-8d19-0242ac130004/4d80dd04-237f-487d-aacd-61ab4625875a-600.png?format=webp 1x, https://api.test.freeda.cloud/public/uploads/543ec95c-db2d-11eb-8d19-0242ac130004/4d80dd04-237f-487d-aacd-61ab4625875a-600.png?format=webp 2x">

None of the externally used images are processed during the build process.
Also no errors are thrown. It seems like this is being ignored.
My nuxt.config:
export default defineNuxtConfig({
   devtools: { enabled: true },
   modules: ["@pinia/nuxt", '@vee-validate/nuxt', '@nuxt/image', 'nuxt-lazy-load', '@nuxtjs/eslint-module', '@nuxtjs/i18n', './modules/extendRoutes.ts'],
   i18n: {
     vueI18n: './i18n.config.ts' // if you are using custom path, default
   },

   css: [
     '~/assets/styles/bulma.scss',
     '~/assets/styles/universal.scss',
     '~/node_modules/@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.min.css'
   ],

   image: {
     providers: {
       freeda: {
         provider: '~/providers/freeda.ts', // Path to custom provider
       }
     }
   },
[ ... ]

My provider freeda.ts
import { joinURL } from 'ufo'
import type { ProviderGetImage } from '@nuxt/image'
import { createOperationsGenerator } from '#image'

const operationsGenerator = createOperationsGenerator()

export const getImage: ProviderGetImage = (
   src,
   { modifiers = {}, baseURL } = {}
) => {

   if (!baseURL) {
     // also support runtime config
     baseURL = useRuntimeConfig().public.MEDIA_BASE
   }

   const operations = operationsGenerator(modifiers)

   return {
     url: joinURL(baseURL, src + (operations ? '?' + operations : '')),
   }
}

Use in the template:
<NuxtImg
             provider="freeda"
             format="webp"
             :src="data.media.variations[1]"
             placeholder
             placeholder-class="freeda-blurred-image"
             loading="lazy"
             style="width: 100%"
           />

Does anyone know of an approach to solving the problem?
I look forward to feedback.
Best regards
